# Submit form with form type entity symfony2

Tags: api, symfony

I trying to update my entity with form type entity of Symfony 2 in following way. I'm using jsonrpc protocol to send json data to server side

```
public functionUpdatMethod($params)
{
    $user = $this->em->getRepository("Repository:User")->find($id);
    $form = $this->formFactory->createBuilder(UserType::class, $user)->getForm();
    $data = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $form->submit(json_decode($data, true));
    $form->isValid()

    if($form->isValid()) { // return true
        try {
            $this->em->flush();

            return "ok";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

`isValid` method returns true, but I've got the following error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'UNIQ_8D93D6495126AC48'

By the way, my form isn't populated with request data.

Answer (score 0):

Has the message error said, you have a violation on your database contraint not your form validation. Looks like you try to record for a second time a field marked with a unique key.